# Compare 2 identical tables for data difference

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in 2 different databases. Name of columns and everything match. How do i run query to see data in both tables are identical. I need to check each row.

Comment: export data tables into files and then white script to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a yes/no answer for the entire data set, and there is at least one key in the table, perform an inner join using all columns, and verify the number of rows returned equals the number of rows in each table.

```
select
    count(*)
from
    a
    inner join b
on
    a.c1 = b.c1 and
    a.c2 = b.c2 and
    a.c3 = b.c3
```

If you need the specific rows that are different from each table as a normalized result, then you will need multiple (at least 2) selects, one to retrieve the unique (non-intersecting) rows from each table. Because of course the tables are identical schemas, you can nicely union these and project a source table column into the results, indicating in which table each row originates.

If you need to correlate resulting differences by the key (as in finding before/after edits, including row content changes, row additions, and row deletes), and your DBMS supports a full outer join, you might perform a full outer join on the key, returning only results where not all columns are equal. Note this assumes the keys are not reused upon deletion.

```
SELECT *
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b
ON a.PK = b.PK
WHERE
    a.c1 <> b.c1 OR
    a.c2 <> b.c2 OR
    a.c3 <> b.c3
```

Note the above example also assumes two null values compare equal, as can be done with a MS SQL via 'SET ANSI NULLS OFF'. It was just faster to express this way.